# Importing jQuery plugins in webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, es6-module-loader

I have searched and found many articles most talking about angular or react. My project includes neither of these.

I am simply trying to import an old jquery module into a js file using webpack.

I have jquery included using this method:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

This works. I can access jquery in the files I need to.

However when I try and import a script for example:

```
import coverflow from '../vendor/coverflow/dist/coverflow';
```

source:
https://github.com/coverflowjs/coverflow

I get a browser error

```
Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
```

When I look this up I see that 'undefined' is referring to document. How is document not defined? Why does this import not work.

using the method:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: require.resolve('./js/vendor/coverflow/dist/coverflow.js'),
        use: "imports-loader?this=>window"
    }
],
```

I get this error:

```html
[0] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
[0]  - configuration has an unknown property 'rules'. These properties are valid:
[0]    object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node
?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?,
 target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
[0]    For typos: please correct them.
[0]    For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
[0]      Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
[0]      Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
[0]      plugins: [
[0]        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
[0]          // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
[0]          options: {
[0]            rules: ...
[0]          }
[0]        })
[0]      ]
```

Comment: is it running in browser or node server?

Comment: the webpack dev server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the library you are using expects **this** to be set to window, but it's not. I had this same problem with [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) and solved it with the [imports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/) like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
  {
    test: require.resolve('modernizr'),
    use: [
      'expose-loader?Modernizr',
      'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?window.Modernizr'
    ]
  }
}
```

The important part being the **this=>window**. You can [read more details about how I solved it here](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-2/).

Comment: So is require.resolve('modernizr') poiting to the path of the plugin?

Comment: It is the name/path of the JS file: node_modules/modernizr/modernizr.js. See here for details: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve

Comment: My module isn't in node_modules.... what path is this relative to? the config file or is it relative to node_moduels? neither seem to work

Comment: Sorry, seeing the updated error in your question, "rules" needs to be within a "module" object. I updated my answer.

Comment: Having read through the article a few times to get my head around it this is the correct answer. Variations of this approach will solve this problem.